# Angular get new scope through another component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ecmascript-6, components

I am building a [component based app](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) project with **angular 1.5.5**

I am creating with d3js some `.floating-node` and for each i create a **new $scope** and append inside a *compiled component*.

This part of the code look like :

```
    nodeEnter.each(() => {
        let childScope = this.$scope.$new();
        childScope.test = "test";
        let compiled = this.$compile('<mycomponent></mycomponent>')(childScope);
        (this.mainContainer).append(compiled);
    });
```

This part of the code work perfectly.

And this is `mycomponent`

```
export default class Mycomponent {
    constructor($scope) {
        console.log($scope.test);         // undefined
        console.log($scope.$parent.test); // test
    }
}
Mycomponent.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

But when I get in my `mycomponent` component. I can't get the right `$scope`.

I checked the `$id` and understand that the `childScope.$id` is in `Mycomponent` `$scope.$id += 1`

I know I can get through with `$scope.$parent` but I will create undesirable `$scope`, and it's not really appreciated in a loop.

So how can I get the same `$scope` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$scope.$new()` in your case because `$compile` is already creating a new instance of scope.

The easier way to solve your issue is to use a querySelector, I guess doing something like the following code should help you :

`newScope = angular.element(document.querySelector("#myId")).isolateScope();`

This way you should now be able to pass data through newScope.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. `.component` will always create it's own, isolated scope and you simply don't use `$scope` in components. If you think it's absolutely necessary in your case, then use `.directive`. I recommend to redesign your component appropriately though.

Comment: You are right ! So i didn't create a new `$scope` and i used the one created by `$compile`. But the probem is now different, how can i get my new scope  crated from the (first) controller ?